# Do percussive massages help treating a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, blood-circulation, massage

I read on http://fortitudesportstherapy.com/percussive-therapy/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170430163543/http://fortitudesportstherapy.com/percussive-therapy/)):

> What is Percussive Massage?
>   Percussive massage is a breakthrough treatment for soft tissue pain.  Percussive massage accelerates the growth and repair of tissues by providing concentrated, rapid, short-duration pulses deep into the tissues of the body.  This heavily increases blood flow to the area causing pain relief and an increasing range of motion and function.  Percussive massage also provides a gentle stretch to the muscles and connective tissues improving responsiveness and performance.
>
> What are the Benefits of Percussive Massage?
>   Percussive massage and muscle stimulation are beneficial in a variety of medical and cosmetic applications, including:
>
> - Relaxing of thickened connective tissue and fascia.
> - Breaking down of adhesions and internal scar tissue, present after injuries or surgery.
> - Increased venous and lymphatic circulation.
> - Elongating muscle fiber, especially when spasms, stiffness and restrictions are present.
> - Increase range of movement by relieving stiff joints.
>
> How do I Know if Percussive Therapy is Right for Me?
>   Percussive therapy is for anyone interested in injury correction, injury prevention, and sports performance.
>
> Common Injuries & Conditions:
>
> - Muscle Soreness
> - Shin Splints
> - Muscle Spasms & Cramps
> - TMJ Syndrome
> - Bursitis
> - Tendonitis
> - Herniated or Bulging Discs
> - Carpal Tunnel Syndrome
> - Sciatica
> - Fibromyalgia

https://www.chuckpechin.com/percussion-therapy echoes these claims.

Is there any scientific evidence supporting or confirming the usefulness of percussive massages to treat a tendinopathy?

I am mostly interested in epicondylopathies (medial or lateral, i.e., tennis elbows and golfer elbows)